# Make even numbered rows fill with specifc color in excel

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I need to have alternation rows in my sheet to be a specific color RGB(142, 169, 219). I have used the =MOD(ROW(),2)=0 but the way my code is when it runs .clear it deletes the color in those rows. I'm trying to put in the code where it just reapplies after the .clear and before ActiveWorkbook.Save. This macro only deletes when the month changes to next month it is set to run and check upon opening the excel file. I would like to not have the mthNum on the spreadsheet in G1 to check for current month but I'm still pretty new to VBA and couldn't think of another way. 
Macro

```
Sub MakeNewSheet()
Dim mthNum As Integer
Dim name As String
todaydate = Format(Date, "MM/DD/YYYY")
mthNum = Month(todaydate)
    name = MonthName(mthNum)
    yearNum = Year(todaydate)
    pdfname = "Jobs_" & name & yearNum
If Range("G1").Value = "" Then Range("G1") = mthNum
    If Range("G1") <> mthNum Then
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\******\Documents\*******\Desktop\" & pdfname
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:F3000").Clear
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").Value = mthNum
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If
End Sub
```

Worksheet

```
Dim mthNum As Integer
todaydate = Format(Date, "MM/DD/YYYY")
mthNum = Month(todaydate)

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("This Number Cannot Be Changed!")
            Target.Offset(1, -6).Activate
        End If
        End If
        Dim nPut As String
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4).Address) <> "" Then GoTo 16

        If Selection.Count = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
            nPut = InputBox("Please Scan Part Number")
            If nPut <> "" Then
            Target.Value = nPut
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            End If
            End If
            End If
  Dim nPut2 As String
16            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 5).Address) <> "" Then Exit Sub
                 If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4).Address) = "" Then Exit Sub
                    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
                        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then

            nPut2 = InputBox("Please Scan Badge")

                    If nPut2 <> "" Then
                    Target.Value = nPut2
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 6).Address) = "" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 6).Address) = todaydate

            Target.Offset(1, -4).Activate

                End If
            Else
            Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: Can you just use a table (Ctrl+T)?

Comment: If you use `ClearContents` instead of `Clear` I don't believe it will remove the color.

Comment: Agreed with BigBen about the table, but if not, why not use conditional formatting rather than VBA?

Comment: @dan I did use conditional formatting and then the code runs to save as pdf and then it deletes the color in the cells too.

Comment: How are you saving it as a PDF? I'm sure you can get it to keep the conditional formats

Comment: @bigben Yeah good Idea let me try that. I'm new to all this and thought I would have to change my code if I converted to a table.

Comment: But tables are great, it's probably worth it.

Comment: @dan I have it set to table and it works but now excel is real slow because of many cells their are when its opening and saving as a PDF.

Comment: Instead of `.Clear`, what if you just did `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:F3000").Value = ""`?

Comment: Got it to work and not take so long by resizing the table. Now when it saves as a PDF it save all rows/columns even if it has no content.